# Detecting the winner of TicTacToe instantly

Tags: javascript

I have looked up for the solutions in the relevant topics but unfortunately, I could not find the proper one. The point is that I do not know what is wrong with my code.
I am trying to make a TicTacToe game as a practice of JS. However, I have difficulties determining the winner. As one of the algorithms suggests, there must be two matrices for player one and player two. The subtraction of matrices shall be calculated and indexed in a final array.
If the addition of the values in the array becomes 3, player one wins, if it's -3, player two wins and if the value is 0, it's a draw. the result shall be calculated instantly. I use the winstats to calculate the sum of those values and determine the winner. Though, in most cases, it is NaN. I would be grateful if you help me with this.

P.S. by instantly, I mean as soon as the 5th action is taken, it has to keep checking for the winning action and declare the winner.

UPDATE: The Codepen link of the project is: https://codepen.io/JoshThePsy/pen/PozqZox

HTML Table:

```
          <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <table id="tictactoefield" class="">
                <tr>
                    <td id="block1" class="blocks" onclick="markNLock(0,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                    <td id="block2" class="" onclick="markNLock(1,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                    <td id="block3" class="blocks" onclick="markNLock(2,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="block4" class=""  onclick="markNLock(3,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                    <td id="block5" class="blocks" onclick="markNLock(4,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                    <td id="block6" class="" onclick="markNLock(5,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="block7" class="blocks" onclick="markNLock(6,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                    <td id="block8" class="" onclick="markNLock(7,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                    <td id="block9" class="blocks" onclick="markNLock(8,this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
                        +
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var turn = false;
var p1socre = 0;
var p2score = 0;
var handresult = 0;
var progresstart = false;
var counterp1 = 0;
var counterp2 = 1;
var insert = 0;
var totalcounter = 0;
var flag = false;
var MatrixFieldP1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var MatrixFieldP2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var MatrixFieldFinal = [];
var winstats = 0;
function startGame() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("startbtn");
    var btnstatus = document.getElementById("startbtn").textContent;
    if (btnstatus == "Start") {
        flag = true;
        btn.textContent = "Stop";
        progress();
    }
    if (btnstatus == "Stop") {
        flag = false;
        btn.textContent = "Start";
        progress();
    }
}
function markNLock(idx, mark) {
    console.log("P1 & P2", mark);
    console.log(MatrixFieldP1, MatrixFieldP2)
    if (flag == false) {
        return;
    }
    if (mark.innerText == "+") {

        if (turn == false) {
            mark.textContent = "X";
            MatrixFieldP1[idx] = 1;
            counterp1 += 2;
            turn = true;

        }
        else {
            mark.textContent = "O";
            MatrixFieldP2[idx] = -1;
            counterp2 += 2;
            turn = false;
        }
        if (totalcounter >= 4) {
            console.log(MatrixFieldFinal);

            for (var i = insert; i < MatrixFieldP2.length; i++) {
                MatrixFieldFinal.push(MatrixFieldP1[i] + MatrixFieldP2[i]);
                console.log(MatrixFieldFinal);
            }
            console.log(MatrixFieldFinal);
            for (var i = insert; i <= MatrixFieldFinal.length; i++) 
            {
                
                winstats += MatrixFieldFinal[i];
                console.log("winstats:", winstats);
                if (winstats == 3) {
                    alert("player 1 won!");
                    winstats = 0;
                }
                else if (winstats == -3) {
                    alert("player 2 won!");
                    winstats = 0;
                }
                else if(winstats == 0)
                {
                    alert("Draw!");
                    
                }
            }
            console.log(MatrixFieldFinal);
            
            insert = 6;
        }
        totalcounter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "instantly" and what about the current code isn't working for you?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: setMouseOutColor is not defined" is being thrown in the background. Could you please prepare a more complete example? you can also put the complete example on https://codepen.io so people can interact and experiment on the code easily.  Also as ggorlen mentioned, it would be nice if you could explain what the problem is and what you are expecting to solve.

Comment: @AntiqTech Thank you for your response. I have added the Codepen link to the post.

Comment: Well the reason you get NaN is  " i <= MatrixFieldFinal.length; " condition in the for loop where you calculate winstat. the array is made up of 9 element. last element is MatrixFieldFinal[8]. Because of that condition, code executes MatrixFieldFinal[9] and gets a NaN since there is not any element with that index. Also move your if/else-if/else check outside of the loop. It fires an alert in most iterations since winstat is 0.

Comment: @AntiqTech Thank you so much for your time. However, it still does not detect the winner properly. I was wondering if the algorithm I was talking about is wrong. the subtraction of two matrices.

Comment: Where did you read about this algorithm, do you have a link ?

Comment: @AntiqTech Sure https://majicdesigns.github.io/MD_TicTacToe/page_library.html

Comment: I took a look at the link, it shows a win matrix. when you click left upper corner (denoted as "a" in that website), the player's matrix should be:[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] but your code shows this after clicking: [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]. This means you're not incorporating that algorithm correctly. You must use that position map (9x8 matrix on the website) to know/use which pattern for which position. You keep two matrices but Algorithm say to keep one. First player moves, update the game matrix by adding the pattern; for Second player, update the game matrix by substracting the pattern.

Comment: @AntiqTech Oh my bad. I figured it out. Thank you.